# replace multiple cells in one in one row of a df with values from same cells in another row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I'm sue the syntax is obvious, but it eludes me...
I need to replace 3 cells in a dataframe with the same cells from another row then replace the source cells with NAs, eg., I need to convert df into df2.

```
V1<-c("A","A","E")
V2<-c("B","D","F")
V3<-c(1,3,5)
V4<-c(2,4,6)
df<-data.frame(V1,V2,V3,V4)
df
V12<-c("A","A","E")
V22<<-c("D",NA,"F")
V32<<-c(3,NA,5)
V42<-c(4,NA,6)
df2<-data.frame(V12,V22,V32,V42)
df2
```

I can do this one cell at a time with dplyr

```
df %>% mutate(V2=replace(V2, V1=="A" & V2=="B","D"))
```

But I can't figure out the syntax for replacing multiple destination cells simultaneously. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 <- df
df2[c(1,2), 2:4] <- rbind(df[2, 2:4], rep(NA, 3))
```

That should do it for you. If you don't want to create a new data frame and save on memory space then,

```
df[c(1,2), 2:4] <- rbind(df[2, 2:4], rep(NA, 3))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

We can rearrange the rows of the data and then assign NA to columns based on the `duplicated` 'V1' values

```
dfN <- df[c(2:1, 3),]
dfN[duplicated(dfN$V1), 2:4] <- NA
row.names(dfN) <- NULL
dfN
#  V1   V2 V3 V4
#1  A    D  3  4
#2  A <NA> NA NA
#3  E    F  5  6
```